# Is there a list of free application modules (or "Fachschalen", in German) for QGIS somewhere?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, template

I'm looking for application modules (in the form of plugins) that cover sets of related tasks like asset management, in a basic UI. A simple use case example: a water gauge (point feature with a 1:n relation to a non-geometry table), that is being maintained/checked periodically; each maintenance gets its own table entry with status/date/etc. The entries are sortable/searchable within the UI using forms.

I went through the plugin-list and the closest thing I could find was norGIS. I did some research and pretty much everything I found was companies offering application module(s) (programming) as service, but couldn't find any templates. Are there none? I realize they'd need tailoring, but not having to start from scratch would be nice. In case there are none, is http://www.qgisworkshop.org/html/workshop/plugins_tutorial.html still the best way to start off?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at http://www.fossgis.de/konferenz/2013/programm/events/532.de.html (german) or the github repository of this project https://github.com/qgep/QGEP

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at the [Midvatten](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/midvatten/) plugin (details in [Midvatten Plugin for QGIS](https://sites.google.com/site/midvattenpluginforqgis/))

> The plugin is intended to be a toolset for using QGIS to manage data from hydrogeological investigations. A spatial-enabled SQLite database (i.e. spatialite) is used for storing data.

[image]